# How to stream data chunk by chunk from Sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I build up a few SQL statements like this by incrementing the offset and then increase the offset

```
"SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() over () LIMIT 1000000 OFFSET 0"
"SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() over () LIMIT 1000000 OFFSET 1000000"
```

and then I use another program to loop over this and increase the offset each time by 1000000. This way I am streaming 100000 records from the data at each iteration.

Is this the most efficient way to get data from Sqlite in a streaming manner?

Comment: Tables are unordered data sets. So using by using `ROW_NUMBER() over ()` in different queries you can never be 100% sure that in all of them the table is sorted the same way. Use `ORDER BY rowid` instead.

Comment: "[*Instead of a row number, you use the last value of the previous page to specify the lower bound. This has a huge benefit in terms of performance because the database can use the ... condition for index access. That means that the database can truly skip the rows from the previous pages. On top of that, you will also get stable results if new rows are inserted.*](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page)" [More info](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset).